# Mapping error code to error description

Tags: c, error-handling, enums

I would have preferred to add a comment to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286874/c-naming-suggestion-for-error-code-enums)
 but didn't have enough points. Consider the following code:

```
enum _config_error
{
    E_SUCCESS = 0,
    E_INVALID_INPUT = -1,
    E_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2, /* consider some way of returning the OS error too */
    ...
};

/* type to provide in your API */
typedef _config_error error_t;

/* use this to provide a perror style method to help consumers out */
struct _errordesc {
    int  code;
    char *message;
} errordesc[] = {
    { E_SUCCESS, "No error" },
    { E_INVALID_INPUT, "Invalid input" },
    { E_FILE_NOT_FOUND, "File not found" },
    ...
};
```

How does one lookup the error description from `errordesc`? I can see two problems with the version I come up with:

```
/* add E_COUNT = 3 to enum _config_error */
const char *errorstring(error_t errnum)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < E_COUNT; ++i) {
        if (errordesc[i].code == errnum) {
            return errordesc[i].message;
        }

    }

    return "Can't reach this point";
}
```

1. One does know the enum size and has to manually set `E_COUNT` to 3.
2. One cannot reach the return after the for loop, what to do there?
3. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can calculate `E_COUNT` from `sizeof(errordesc) / sizeof(struct _errordesc)`.
2. If you reach the end of the loop, simply return `"Unknown error"` or something similar.
3. Since your error codes seems to be consecutive (but negative) you could index directly into the array using `-errnum`.

Comment: The error codes are only consecutive, since I copied them from the original example. I would prefer not to rely on this fact.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Then I think your current solution is fine. You should calculate the number of error codes though as suggested in 1.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to ensure all your error codes have successive values from 0 up (or down). Then you can use them as indices into `errordesc[]`. Of course, if they are negative, you would do something like `errordesc[-errnum]`.

As for the number of entries in `errordesc[]`, it's `sizeof(errordesc)/sizeof(errordesc[0])`. You can store it in a global variable.

There's also `bsearch()` in C...

Comment: If one uses the error codes as indices to `errordesc[]` one has to manually keep track that there are no mistakes. Also I like that the error codes are next to their description.